# scrolling in uitableview with uitextview

Tags: uitableview, uitextview

I have a uitableview with custom uitableviewcell. To hide keyboard user should scroll up or down. I reach this by implementing this method

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (_isEnableHide) {
        [self resignFirstResponderForVisibleCells];
    }
}
```

But

When cell is selected and keyboard is on, I try to scroll but strange behavior begins. It begins to scroll after keyboard disappears  and any scrollings stops .

[image]

I want to uitableview down with keyboard.

I try manually do this by animation like this

```
....
 tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
 tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
.....
```

but after scrolling on tableview stops tableview down and tableview's insets are negative KEYBOARHEIGHT. How to scroll down tableview and keyboard together or cancel auto moving down after scrolls stop to make it manually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved this problem by setting self.tableView.scrollEnabled to No and change that after keyboard disappear to YES. 
But proper scrolling don't occur after that.
To solve this we manually scrolling tableView

```
CGRect rect = self.frame;
if (isDown) {
  rect.origin.y +=someDistance;
}else{
  rect.origin.y -= someDistance;
}
[tableView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
```